# How to draw proper vertical text in a CGContext?

Tags: swift, cocoa, core-graphics, textkit, vertical-text

I need to draw an `NSAttributedString` to a `CGContext` using a vertical layout orientation (ie. a vertical “writing direction”). It is not sufficient to rotate horizontally-typeset lines of text, because that doesn’t activate vertical OpenType features or consider in which scripts the glyphs should be upright (ex: Chinese).

**This is already possible with an `NSTextView`.** The layout orientation of an `NSTextView` can be either horizontal or vertical either by setting a [`NSLayoutManager.TextLayoutOrientation`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nslayoutmanager/textlayoutorientation) value or, via the UI by right-clicking inside the view. But I need to draw the text *into a Core Graphics PDF context—not a view*.

I don’t see anything about vertical typesetting in CoreText, but I’m guessing that TextKit is capable of this. It appears that TextKit’s NSTextContainer can be [subclassed to use a vertical orientation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nstextlayoutorientationprovider), and that seems like an important part of the puzzle. I’m currently doing that like so:

```swift
class VerticalTextContainer: NSTextContainer {
    override var layoutOrientation: NSLayoutManager.TextLayoutOrientation { .vertical }
}
```

I’m new to TextKit and can’t find many examples of people using it with a CGContext instead of a view, so I’m sure I’m setting this up incorrectly. Here’s my TextKit set up:

```swift
let attrString = NSAttributedString(
    string: "Hello 你好！"
)

/// The text box; the shape/frame to fill with the text.
let textContainer: NSTextContainer = VerticalTextContainer(size: NSSize(width: 300, height: 300) )

/// The part that handles laying out text elements, generating text layout fragments.
let textLayoutManager: NSTextLayoutManager = {
    var layoutManager = NSTextLayoutManager()
    layoutManager.textContainer = textContainer
    return layoutManager
}()

/// The part that stores the attributed string and connects to the layout manager.
let textContentStorage: NSTextContentStorage = {
    var storage = NSTextContentStorage()
    storage.attributedString = attrString
    storage.addTextLayoutManager( textLayoutManager )
    return storage
}()
```

Then, in my CGContext, I’ve tried this—but nothing appears:

```swift
// inside a new 300x300 CGContext:

// prep:
cgContext.scaleBy(x: 1, y: -1)
cgContext.translateBy(x: 0, y: size.height * -1)
cgContext.textMatrix = .identity
cgContext.setFillColor( .black )

// try drawing the TextKit line fragments
textLayoutManager.enumerateTextLayoutFragments(
    from: textLayoutManager.documentRange.location,
    options: .ensuresLayout
) { textLayoutFragment in
    textLayoutFragment.draw(at: CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100), in: cgContext)
    return true
}
```

I’ve tried many variations on this, including passing `nil` to the enumerate method’s `from:` parameter, iterating over each of the `textLayoutFragment.textLineFragments` and drawing each one, and doing `textLayoutManager.ensureLayout(for: textLayoutFragment.rangeInElement)`. Nothing seems to work. I’m not even sure if the layout fragments are being created.

Any help would be so appreciated!

Comment: How about making a `NSTextView` anyway, and draw the layer of the `NSTextView` into the context? See [`render(in:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/calayer/1410909-render)

Comment: @Sweeper One reason I’d rather not create a view is because I’d like this to run off the main thread. Nor do I need interactivity or the other features of a view, which could decrease performance in demanding cases.

Comment: Does it work if you don't change the layout orientation, don't scale and don't translate?

Comment: @Willeke Just tried every combination of those, but they didn’t change the result.

Comment: I tried your code and the (horizontal) text appears.

Comment: Thanks @Willeke. That inspired me to do a few more experiments, and I discovered that the code works in a Swift playground but not in a new Mac app project (at least not with my set up). I will investigate that further. I was finally able to get it working in a playground. I will clean that up and share my solution soon.